# Getting EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'getCookie' of null with angular-stormpath on webpack

Tags: angular, webpack-dev-server, express-stormpath

I'm trying to get this project: https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-angular2-express-example running on webpack. The application starts up, but when the first page loads I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCookie' of null
at CookieXSRFStrategy.configureRequest (app.js:51374)
at XHRBackend.createConnection (app.js:51414)
at httpRequest (app.js:51752)
at StormpathHttp.Http.get (app.js:51863)
at StormpathHttp.get (app.js:78381)
at Stormpath.getAccount (app.js:49917)
at new Stormpath (app.js:49906)
at _View_AppComponent_Host0.createInternal (host.ngfactory.js:20)
at _View_AppComponent_Host0.AppView.create (app.js:42393)
at _View_AppComponent_Host0.DebugAppView.create (app.js:42593)
```

I have a sample repo setup here: https://github.com/djkrite/ng2-stormpath-webpack-example

I've tried to use:

```
BrowserDomAdapter.makeCurrent();
```

before the bootstrap call, but that ends up throwing another error about unexpected token import.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue by cloning your repo and running `npm install && npm start`. When I do this, there's nothing running on localhost:4200, but it does seem to be running on localhost:3000. When I open localhost:3000, I see the following error in my console: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/mraible/dev/ng2-stormpath-webpack-example/index.html'
   at Error (native)`

Comment: Webpack is running on https://localhost:4200 (https) and there's express running on http://localhost:3000. Stormpath requests get proxied to the express server on port 3000. It should work just like this: https://stormpath.com/blog/angular-2-user-authentication, but with webpack instead of "ng serve". Here's a screen shot:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3n94fXDBWwheE1vVmpHbjJQUWM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Aahhh, I missed the HTTPS in localhost:4200. I'm investigating now.

Answer (score 1):

Good news! I figured out how to make ng2-stormpath-webpack-example work. I think the root cause of the problem is the typescript configuration (`tsconfig.json`) was in the src directory and webpack expects it in the root directory. Here's the `tsconfig.json` file that works (remember, I moved it to the root directory):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
  }
}
```

I changed the webpack loaders in `webpack.config.js` to be:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader?keepUrl=true'],
        exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/, /node_modules/]
      },
      /* Embed files. */
      {
        test: /\.(html|css)$/,
        loader: 'raw-loader',
        exclude: /\.async\.(html|css)$/
      },
      /* Async loading. */
      {
        test: /\.async\.(html|css)$/,
        loaders: ['file?name=[name].[hash].[ext]', 'extract']
      }
    ]
  }
```

I also removed the empty resolve extension:

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
  },
```

Finally, in `package.json`, I added types for Protractor and upgraded to Webpack 2.x.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.53.33",
    ...
    "webpack": "2.2.0-rc.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
```

Here's a pull request with the fix: https://github.com/djkrite/ng2-stormpath-webpack-example/pull/1